# Cleaner way to access superview in Swift?

Tags: swift, uikit

The `superview` property of UIView is an optional: `UIView?`. In my class, I know that after I initialize my view, the child views will always have a set superview. Is there anything cleaner than `childview.superview!`?

Here is some example context:

```
bgView.constrain_edges(to: bgView.superview!)
```

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by `cleaner`. `bgView.superview!` is already very clean to me. What do you want?

Answer (score 1):

Sure the cleaner way to do this would be:

```
if let superview = self.superview {
    bgView.constrain_edges(to: superview)
}
```

Conditionally unwrapping optionals is the cleaner way to access any optional value including a view's `superView`. Routinely using the `!` bang operator in your code to access optionals makes your code sad. Unwrapping optionals safely or using a default (below) makes your code happy.

```
bgView.constrain_edges(to: self.superView ?? self.view)
```

Comment: Except I'm 100% certain my superview is set.

Comment: In this case you may use the bang operator. But only if you promise to be a good boy with it.

Comment: It's already insulting enough that Swift treats me like a child. Don't you start.